# Create empty python bytearray inside function that modifies calling variable

Tags: python

I want to create a function that will modify an input parameter. Sometimes, I want to reassign the input parameter to an empty bytearray, but have that empty bytearray be modified at the calling level. For example:

```
def modify(current_bytes, new_byte):
    current_bytes += new_byte # this modifies calling variable no problem
    if check_done(current_bytes):
        current_bytes = bytearray()  # this does not modify higher level variable
    if check_error(current_bytes):
        current_bytes = new_byte # WILL THIS WORK?
```

I believe the reason is that the `current_bytes` inside the function is now pointing to a NEW object, which is an empty bytearray. But how do I ensure that the `current_bytes` variable will always be modifying the higher level variable?

Also, if I do `current_bytes = new_byte` will this modify the higher level calling object as well?

Comment: Try `current_bytes[:] = some_new_value`.

Comment: `current_bytes[:] = b''` will empty bytearray itself.

Comment: That works, but I'm not exactly sure why. In reading, [:] creates a shallow copy. I am not sure exactly why a shallow copy is helping here.